# Isolating coefficients from polynomial fit in r

Tags: r, polynomial-math

I have fitted a simple 2nd order polynomial to time series data in the following form:

```
polyfit <- lm(y ~ poly(x,2))
```

I wish to extract the respective coefficients (A, B and C) from the fitted polynomial of the form y = Ax^2 + Bx + C. I naturally thought the answer would be found in polyfit$coefficients within the polyfit object but these coefficients are not correct. I have tried some very simple data sets and compared with excel and whilst the poly curve fits are identical in R and excel, the A,B and C coefficints obtained from excel are correct but those obtained from the polyfit object arent? Have I extracted the incorrect information from the polyfit object? It would be more convenient for me to extract the coefficients directly from R for my purposes? Can anyone help?

Comment: Provide a reproducible example with data (fake or real) and you will be much more likely to get the answer you're looking for.

Comment: If you want a regular polynomial you have to do `poly(x,2,raw=TRUE)` for otherwise R will fit an orthogonal polynomial

Comment: Thank-you RoyalTS all works perfectly now, cheers Phil

Comment: @RoyalTS `raw = TRUE` also changes the fitting procedure and thus might lead to a different polynomial. People argue that raw = FALSE gives the better fit. So is there an easy way to obtain formulas for the orthogonal polynomials?

Answer (score 5):

By default `poly` fits orthogonal polynomials.  Essentially it uses the following ideas...

```
x <- 1:10

# in this case same as x-mean(x)
y1 <- residuals(lm(x ~ 1)) 
# normalize to have unit norm
y1 <- y1/sqrt(sum(y1^2))

y2 <- residuals(lm(y1^2 ~ y1))
y2 <- y2/sqrt(sum(y2^2))

y3 <- residuals(lm(x^3 ~ y2 + y1))
y3 <- y3/sqrt(sum(y3^2))

cbind(y1, y2, y3)    
poly(x, 3)
```

to construct a set of orthonormal vectors that still produce the same predictions.  If you just want to get a polynomial in the regular way then you want to specify `raw=TRUE` as a parameter.

```
y <- rnorm(20)
x <- 1:20
o <- lm(y ~ poly(x, 2, raw = TRUE))
# alternatively do it 'by hand'
o.byhand <- lm(y ~ x + I(x^2))
```

Comment: Thank-you Dason I was missing the "raw=TRUE" parameter, all works perfectly now, much obliged Phil

Comment: @PhilW While `raw = TRUE` gives the desired output, it also changes the fitting procedure and thus might lead to a different polynomial.  People argue that `raw = FALSE` gives the better fit.  So is there an easy way to obtain formulas for the orthogonal polynomials?