# Isolating a formula for a polynomial fit in r

Tags: r, polynomials, polynomial-approximations

This is a generalization of [Isolating coefficients from polynomial fit in r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16474314/isolating-coefficients-from-polynomial-fit-in-r) (which does not cover the case of polynomials) and (in a sense) a duplicate of [Isolating coefficients from polynomial fit in r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16474314/isolating-coefficients-from-polynomial-fit-in-r) (which, after 4 years, only has a partial answer/"workaround"; see my remark about `raw = TRUE` below).

Suppose I have a polynomial fit:

```
l <- lm(mpg ~ poly(cyl, disp, hp, degree = 2), mtcars)
summary(l)
```

Is there an easy way to obtain the polynomial formula behind it?

I understand that `poly` works with orthogonal polynomials and that the option `raw = TRUE` will work with monomials.  Thus, with `raw = TRUE` it is much easier to extract a formula.  However, I have been told that `raw = TRUE` will, in general, give a different (worse?) fit.

Comment: You say that the second cited post has no accepted answer after 4 years.  That is technically true. However, the OP made a comment that one of the answers "works perfectly". I think that could be counted as an answer.

Comment: @G5W Agreed, I will reformulate

Comment: I guess, I don't understand what exactly do we mean by *the coefficients of the polynomial*?

Comment: The coefficients of `x - 2 x^2` are 1 and -2.  But if `lm` returns `poly(x, degree = 2)1 = 1` and `poly(x, degree = 2)2 = -2`, then these coefficients are not the coefficients that appear in front of `x` or `x^2`.  Instead, everything depends on the data: `poly` (or `lm`?) constructs orthogonal polynomials of degree 1 and 2, and the final polynomial is a combination of these orthogonal polynomials, with certain coefficients.  It is these coefficients that are reported.